# Can mobile apps be updated from remote server once published?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, react-native

I am new to mobile development and basically I have a web app that's built on PHP/MySQL to sell stock images. But I want to create an Android/iOS version of the site with some of the basic core functionalities from site but main use for it is to access to camera and GPS functions of the phone. Take photos and upload it to my site. I want it to feel like a native app. So was thinking of using ReactJS.

Some newbie questions I have are:

1) Is ReactJS best way to do this or anyone have better suggestions? Main thing is speed and native look and feel for Android/iOS.

2) Is it possible to change the end-points of the app once it's published? Lets say I want to change the domain of my site once the app is published. Is it possible to have the mobile app get configuration options from my server each time it's run so it can be updated with different layouts, ads, end-points for uploads, etc? Or is that stuff locked on the mobile app?

3) Any apps already out there that's similar to what I need and I can use as a starting point? (That I can buy to use or open-source?) Or anyone interested in building it for me as paid side project? :-)

Comment: For 2nd question I would recommend to use `Firebase Remote Config` to update your app. It is very easy to implement.

Comment: @TOP awesome! Good to know. Seems exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. React Native has good performance compared to other alternatives out there. But if you are going for the speed and native look and feel, writing platform specific code in either Xcode or Android Studio will take you further.
2. Yes, it is possible to change the endpoint on app launch. It is completely up to how you architecture the app. However, there should be a server which updates the app about the configuration changes. May I suggest, instead of downloading the configuration on each time the app launches, you could use Apple Push Notification Service or Google Cloud Messaging to push the configuration changes.
3. Sure, there are. Flickr, off the top of my head

Comment: You can also use Firebase Remote Config to set/change your end point when needed.

Comment: I just stumbled across www.fusetools.com while looking at Ionic. Anyone have experience with it for building camera apps?